# Perl Regex- how to use localFile(.txt) for matching

Tags: regex, perl, authentication, blacklist

I'm working on a project that requires to add some Password Authentication using Perl Regular Expressions.

The only thing that i have is a line textblock ,imagine something like this: https://rubular.com/r/9OZvpmtUpP. And for that reason i can put programming code there but only regular expressions *[for example :^abc$]*.

Also i can use only one textblock so i have to combine all the expressions in "one" line.

So far i complete 2 requirements:

1. match if at least 3 types of chars included

*(((?=.{4,})((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W_])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])).*))*

2. containing many(4 max) of the same characters

(?=^(?:(.)(?!(?:.*?\1){4}))*$)

and i combine them like this:

```
(((?=.{4,})((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W_])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])).*))(?=^(?:(.)(?!(?:.*?\1){4}))*$)
```

Now i have 2 requirements to go. The first one is to read a blacklist from a local file (.txt) words that included [one row one word] and not to match with them)

```
     for example :    |  BadWord
   path/myText.txt    |  TestingWord
  have these 3 words  |  TestingBlacklist
```

These words must not my Included in a password

The second requirement is that the password except these 3 req above must not have over 2  times a char repetition

```
     for example :    Z@2gmacaiooi*77    Match - 2 times a char reppeated
                      982iuionjna%$sd    Match - 0 times a char reppeated
                      88asf$$1233ada4  NO MatcH- 3 times a char reppeated
```

Its important that the regex is in this format so i can make the join in one regex line. Thank you

Comment: As an aside, the first pattern has a boat-load of problems. It should be `^(?=.*{4,})(?=.\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])`

Comment: As an aside, the second pattern is wrong too. I don't know what you are trying to match, though.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

```
(((?=.{4,})((?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])|(?=.\d)(?=.[a-zA-Z])(?=.[\W_])|(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[\W_])).))
```

I am of one mind with Abigail, simply doesn't make sense
if you appreciate rearrange and rewrite your problem neatly

`... (?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z]) ...`is it possible ?... isn't it `(?i)` or `(?-i)` default case sensitive etc..